# @Valid and @NotNull Annotations does not catch empty field in post request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi I have one field JSON POST Request.

```
import lombok.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebURLRequest {

    @NotNull(message = "URL can not be null")
    private String url;
}
```

In Controller, I have annotated as `@Valid` and `@RequestBody` but when I sent a post request like this I except to this returned a meaningful message as I write down in DTO.
Instead of this message, since url is not found in request body, Service layer throws `NullPointerException`.
I know I can handle this in Service layer or in Controller with a Null check but shouldn't this handled by `@NotNull` annotation?

Controller

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@PostMapping("/to-deep")
    public ResponseEntity<DeepResponse> toDeep(@Valid @RequestBody WebURLRequest webURLRequest) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(converterService.toDeep(webURLRequest), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

The request body I sent

```
{
"somethingElse":""
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

I added this dependency to pom file

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: empty is something different than `null`. Use `@NotEmpty` instead of `@NotNull`.

Comment: there is no field "url" in request body. Isn't that mean url is null?

Comment: Oops, just saw an empty field. Do you have an actual implementation of a validator on the classpath? Or did you only add `javax.validation-api`? If so add `hibernate-validator` as a dependency as well (use the 6 version **not** the 7 version as that is JakartaEE not JavaEE). Or when using Spring Boot use `spring-boot-starter-validation` to get all of that at once.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. How could I detect this pom or "correct package" related problems from project?

Comment: What worked? You added the additional dependency or the correct one? Only an API does nothing adding `javax.persistence-api` doesn't add a JPA provider as well. So you need to have both an API and an Implementation.

Comment: I added `spring-boot-starter-validation` to the pom file.

Comment: @erondem add your solution as an answer and accept it so that others may benefit from it ;) Thanks!

Comment: for string use @NotEmpty instead of NotNull

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @M. Deinum I added this dependency to pom file and it solves my problem.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```